# (TCP?) My computer has trouble connecting to other services

Tags: macos, tcp, macos-sierra

Noticed that last night, my Discord voice channels would not connect (RTC connecting, then No Route), and League of Legends would not let me log in (Authenticating forever, but others could see my account online). My other computer could connect to League of Legends while this one couldn't.

Mac Firewall has both applications allowing connections.  Tried turning off Real-Time protection from Avira, to no avail.  This has never happened before.
Tried on two different wifi connections.

Tried using https://test.webrtc.org/ as Discord recommended, and all is good, but it seems unable to continue once it tries to check TCP.  I'm assuming this means that something about my TCP is faulty.

This would make sense, considering the definition of TCP:

> TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) is a standard that defines how to establish and maintain a network conversation via which application programs can exchange data. TCP works with the Internet Protocol (IP), which defines how computers send packets of data to each other.

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

**EDIT:  Tried removing Avira Anti-virus, and still is a problem.
Also tried exchanging DNSs, still nothing...**

Comment: 2 things to try. 1) Uninstall Avira completely [using their uninstaller, not manually] 2) test a different DNS, try 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my VPNs were glitching out like crazy, and couldn't turn them off at all (if I tried turning it off in System Preferences, it would reconnect within a second.

My problem was that I had unwittingly turned the VPN on, quitted the application, then deleted the app.  This meant that the VPN didn't know that it needed to turn off, and I didn't have the controls to turn it off again...

I went to System Preferences => Network and **removed the VPN from the list**, and applied changes.  Then it started trying to connect to my other VPN.  **I accessed the second VPN's application, turned it off**, and everything worked fine after that.